# Trash order send email wooocommerce

Tags: email, woocommerce

Hello what is the hook to send an email when the order is moved to the trash?

I have this code that works when the order is canceled or fails but I also need to send an email when the order is moved to the trash.

```json
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'send_custom_email_notifications', 10, 4 );
function send_custom_email_notifications( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if ( $new_status == 'cancelled' || $new_status == 'failed' ){
        $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails(); // Get all WC_emails objects instances
        $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email(); // The customer email
    }

    if ( $new_status == 'cancelled' ) {
        // change the recipient of this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']->recipient = $customer_email;
        // Sending the email from this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
    } 
    elseif ( $new_status == 'failed' ) {
        // change the recipient of this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Failed_Order']->recipient = $customer_email;
        // Sending the email from this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Failed_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'send_custom_email_notifications', 10, 4 );
function send_custom_email_notifications( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){
    if ( $new_status == 'cancelled' || $new_status == 'failed' || 'trash' == get_post_meta($order_id, 'post_status', true) ){ //added extra condition here
        $wc_emails = WC()->mailer()->get_emails(); // Get all WC_emails objects instances
        $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email(); // The customer email
    }

    if ( $new_status == 'cancelled' ) {
        // change the recipient of this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']->recipient = $customer_email;
        // Sending the email from this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Cancelled_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
    } 
    elseif ( $new_status == 'failed' ) {
        // change the recipient of this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Failed_Order']->recipient = $customer_email;
        // Sending the email from this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Failed_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
    } 
    elseif ( 'trash' == get_post_meta($order_id, 'post_status', true) ) {
        // change the recipient of this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Failed_Order']->recipient = $customer_email;
        // Sending the email from this instance
        $wc_emails['WC_Email_Failed_Order']->trigger( $order_id ); //trigger some email here
    } 
}
```

Comment: I did the mentioned but apparently "trash" is not within the parameters of "woocommerce_order_status_changed"

Comment: It is ok if it's not in the arguments. The trash is a post_status of the post_type shop_order for standard wordpress. Instead of 'trash' == get_post_status($order_id) you can try 'trash' == get_post_meta($order_id, 'post_status', true)   that might help